# Overwrite destination with hadoop fs mv?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Doing a quick test of the form

```
testfunc() {
    hadoop fs -rm /test001.txt
    hadoop fs -touchz /test001.txt
    hadoop fs -setfattr -n trusted.testfield -v $(date +"%T") /test001.txt
    hadoop fs -mv /test001.txt /tmp/.
    hadoop fs -getfattr -d /tmp/test001.txt
}
testfunc()
testfunc()
```

resulting in output

```
... during second function call
mv: '/tmp/test001.txt': File exists
# file: /tmp/test001.txt
trusted.testfield="<old timestamp from first call>"
...
```

it seems like (unlike in linux) the `hadoop fs mv` command does not overwrite a destination file if already exists. Is there a way to force overwrite behavior (I suppose I could check and delete the destination each time, but something like `hadoop mv -overwrite <source> <dest>` would be more convenient for my purposes)?

** By the way if, I am interpreting the results incorrectly or the behavior just seems incorrect, let me know (as I had assumed that overwriting was the default behavior and am writing this question *because* I was surprised that it seemed not to be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no straight option to move and overwrite files from one HDFS location to other although copying (cp command) has the option to force (using -f). From Apache Hadoop documentation (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html), it is said that Hadoop is designed to use write-once-read-many model which limited overwriting.